# How do I make an actor send messages back to the caller?

Tags: scala, actor, self

I'm trying to reproduce this [example](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/wikla/OTS/Sisalto/examples/html/ch30.html#sec4).
Everything compiles, but when I run it, all my results look like this:

```
  scala> NameResolver ! ("www.scala-lang.org", self)

  scala> self.receiveWithin(0) { case x => x }
  res0: Any = TIMEOUT // and not Some(www.scala-lang.org/128.178.154.102)

  scala> NameResolver ! ("wwwwww.scala-lang.org", self)

  scala> self.receiveWithin(0) { case x => x }
  res1: Any = TIMEOUT // and not None
```

Here is my example:

```
import scala.actors._
import scala.actors.Actor._

case class Plus(x: Int, y: Int)

val concurrentCalculator = actor {
   while(true)
      receive {
         case Plus(x, y) => println(x + y)
         case (Plus(x, y), caller: Actor) => caller ! (x + y)
      }
}

scala> concurrentCalculator ! Plus(2,3)
5

scala> concurrentCalculator ! (Plus(2,3), self)

scala> self.receiveWithin(1000) { case x => x }
res0: Any = TIMEOUT // WTF?
```

So why am I getting a `TIMEOUT` instead of a valid result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check that `self` returns different values on different calls not within a code block, due to the way Scala REPL works (every expression to be evaluated is compiled into a separate class):

```
scala> self
res3: scala.actors.Actor = scala.actors.ActorProxy@1bb0ff0

scala> self
res4: scala.actors.Actor = scala.actors.ActorProxy@46530
```

In one block of code it will work even if it isn't explicitly declared as an actor:

```
scala> {
     | concurrentCalculator ! (Plus(2,3), self)
     | self.receiveWithin(1000) { case x => x }
     | }
res9: Any = 5
```

Comment: Thx a lot. It kinda sucks that the example I tried to reproduce was taken out of the Book "Programming in Scala" (or from the link I posted directly in the question) and they obviously use the REPL. Nothing is perfect, I guess...

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that `import scala.actors.Actor._` defines a method called `self` which is, indeed, an actor. My bad.

Comment: Well, that book was written for Scala 2.7, when each actor took up a thread, so that worked. But this is no longer the case. Scala is a rather fast-moving target :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the calling code is not an actor, so the second case in your `concurrentCalculator` actor does not match.

Try this, instead, and you should see what you expect:

```
val me = actor { 
  concurrentCalculator ! (Plus(2,3), self); 
  self.receiveWithin(1000) { case x => println(x) } 
}
```